# Why does Azure Mobile app is setting value to identity column

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have an azure mobile app.In my asp.net backend i have set and identity column.so database will assign value itself but azure mobile app sends value for every column.Why is that so? Even when i skip column name it sends null.How can i avoid this?

My Backend migrations is

```
 Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
```

Answer (score -1):

If you didn't use the backend server SDK for Azure Mobile Apps, please use the SDK in your backend project. More information for your reference: [Work with the .NET backend server SDK for Azure Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk)

In backend server SDK, we need to make our entities extend the abstract class `EntityData`

And there already has been a identity column named `Id` in `EntityData` as below:

[image]

So we don't have to define an identity column of int type, we just need to let our entities extend `EntityData` and database will assign value of `Id` in `EntityData` automatically.